# Find sum of objects inside array using reduce

Tags: node.js

I am trying to find the total from objects inside an array, which each object has a price and quantity, 
i can find the total when the array has exactly two objects, but for more than two it produces `NaN`.

```
arr = [ { quantity: 1, price: 30 },
{ quantity: 1, price: 40 },
{ quantity: 2, price: 10 },
{ quantity: 1, price: 10 } ]


const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => {
    var a = accumulator.quantity * accumulator.price;
    var b = currentValue.quantity * currentValue.price;
    return a + b;
}
console.log(arr.reduce(reducer));  // sum if array contains 2 objects, NaN otherwise.
```

Comment: `accumulator` won't have a `quantity` or `price` properties, since it's the result of the last return value. Since you do `a + b`, you'd only get a number the first time, but on the second iteration, you'll have `accumulator = <previous>a + <previous>b`

Comment: Check out the docs for reduce, specifically what it used as the initial accumulator value if none is provided.

Comment: @DaveNewton the *initial* is OK, in this case. But only the initial. There is a problem for anything other than two items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    let arr = [ 
    { quantity: 1, price: 30 },
    { quantity: 1, price: 40 },
    { quantity: 2, price: 10 },
    { quantity: 1, price: 10 } 
    ]

    let reducer = (acc, cur) => {
     return acc + (Number(cur.quantity) * Number(cur.price));
    };

    console.log(arr.reduce(reducer, 0));
    // 100
```

Your reducer function seems to be wrong. Accumulator no longer has any parameters to it, since well, it accumulates - its an integer.
Also, set a initial value for your accumulator to start accumulating from, as shown in the reduce function, second parameter input

Comment: Why explicitly convert the numbers to numbers?

Comment: Just in case somewhere in the input object, the value is stored as string

Comment: None are here, so it's a bit useless to think of this case. And what if the value is a boolean? And what if it's `undefined`? What if the value is a string but it's `"apple"`? Not really worth it solving all these potential issues. Not to mention that the `*` operator will do an implicit casting to number for both operands. Even *if* one of the values is the string `"10"` instead of the number `10` that will be handled. And you'll still have the same problems with non-numeric strings and other types.

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [ { quantity: 1, price: 30 },
{ quantity: 1, price: 40 },
{ quantity: 2, price: 10 },
{ quantity: 1, price: 10 } ]

const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) {
    return accumulator + (currentValue.quantity * accumulator.price);
}

console.log(arr.reduce(reducer, 0 ));
```

Answer (score -1):

you can simply say

```js
arr = [ { quantity: 1, price: 30 },
{ quantity: 1, price: 40 },
{ quantity: 2, price: 10 },
{ quantity: 1, price: 10 } ]


const total = arr.reduce((total,item)=>{
   total +=  item.quantity * item.price;
  return total
},0)
```

Comment: not the callback doesn't return anything. The whole `reduce` will return `undefined`.